# Find what time it's in a different timezone in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am trying to localize the time for a guy in Australia to see his local time instead of the USA time.

I know he is at GMT+10:00 and I have a DateTime at my hands but I cannot find the way to translate that datetime to his local time (DateTime is at server time[USA-somewhere])

I have tried to do the following

```
DateTime fromDt = DateTime.Now;//just for presentation (it really comes from API)
string timezone = "+1000";       
var dd = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " " 
+ timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it doesn't translate the local time to Australian but it translate the time to USA if it was Australian.

Can you point me the way how to translate the local USA time to Australian?

Comment: Convert from your local time to Utc time, then convert the result to your required timezone. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you not just do fromDt.AddHours(10)?  - just reading that, you'd obviously have to first convert to GMT from your local time offset. Apologies, I oversimplified.

Comment: After you clean it to invariant don't you need to apply a CultureInfo.CurrentCulture or something?

Comment: Also, - you must know *which* time zone it is originating from.  +10:00 is not enough information because it could be `"AUS Eastern Standard Time"` (Sydney, Melbourne, etc. use DST) or `"E. Australia Standard Time"` (Brisbane, Lindeman, etc. do not use DST).   See also [Time in Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DateTimeOffset` will really come in handy here. It's a `DateTime` but you can also specify the GMT Offset. For example:

```
var gmtTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow; //time at +0:00
var usaEastTime = gmtTime.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(-4, 0, 0)); //time at -4:00
var austTime = gmtTime.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)); //time at +10:00
```

The big thing to keep in mind is to remember what the timezones of your variables are, and don't mix them up.

It's also much better to look up the offset values rather than manually plug in numbers. Right now EST for USA is -4, but in a few months it will be -5.

So, to incorporate a varent of [Brian Rudolph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26107718), you can lookup the offset using the timezone name, then plug that TimeSpan into the `ToOffset` function.

```
var gmtTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
var ausTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
var austTime = gmtTime.ToOffset(ausTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset);
```

It just so happens that `ausTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset` is +10:00, though if that changes then your code will reflect the change as well.

Comment: Offsets can change.  You can use `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset` for a particular date/time, but you cannot assume that the base offset applies all year round.

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(fromDt , "AUS Eastern Standard Time");
```

Comment: Will it return daylight saving time during that period?

Comment: RE: Timeless, "AUS Eastern Standard Time" is used for New South Wales, ACT and Victoria so it will contain daylight saving then those regions switch to it.